# How to use websocket npm library in browser?

Tags: node.js, websocket, browserify

I started learning node.js. I want to make a chat application using websockets. In console it's working fine. But in browser i'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I googled and saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/2689414). I want to try browserify but it's not working properly. Here is my js file

**client.js**:

```
var WebSocket = require('websocket');
var connector;
var WebSocketClient = WebSocket.client;
var client = new WebSocketClient();


client.on('connectFailed', function (error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
    setTimeout(self.connect, 2000);
});

client.on('connect', function (connection) {
    connector = connection;
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function (error) {
        errorStr = error.toString();
        console.log("Connection Error: " + errorStr);
    });
    connection.on('close', function () {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function (message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });
    connection.sendUTF("Hello");
    sender("Working");

});

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("It's an Err " + err.toString());
});

function connect() {
    client.connect('ws://localhost:8765/', 'echo-protocol');
}

function sender(str) {
    connector.sendUTF(str);
}
connect();
```

Here is the problem. When I run bunddle.js.

```
$ browserify  client.js > bunddle.js
$ node bunddle.js
/home/user/udb/sgg/node/chat/bundle.js:5
var client = new WebSocketClient();
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: In short, can't. https://github.com/websockets/ws says `Note: This module does not work in the browser.`

Answer (score 11):

The `websocket` library you are using involves some native C++ bindings. These are incompatible with browserify so you cannot use it. You should use the library only in your server-implementation and in your client.js that runs in the browser you should use the [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object.

Browsers provide their own [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object. The `websocket` NPM package you are using is a Node.js implementation of the browser-standard `WebSocket` interface (Well, the `websocket.W3CWebSocket` class anyway).

Essentially in browsers you should not need `require('websocket')` or anything similar as the browsers already provide you with the WebSocket. See the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) for an example of using WebSockets in the browser.

Of course given WebSockets provide a communication method between two endpoints, you will need an endpoint with which your browser will communicate. This is where you need a package like the `websocket`: Implementing the server-side endpoint with which the browser communicates.

Answer (score 4):

From the doc itself:
https://github.com/websockets/ws

> Note: This module does not work in the browser. The client in the docs is a reference to a back end with the role of a client in the WebSocket communication.
>
> Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object. To make the same code work seamlessly on Node.js and the browser
>
> you can use one of the many wrappers available on npm, like **isomorphic-ws**.

The native api and implementation is just cool and sufficient

(don't see a motivation for isomorphic-ws)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

### init

> webSocket = new WebSocket(url, protocols);

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.example.com/socketserver");
```

### send and json

You need to `JSON.stringify`. And **ws** in the backend will handle it all right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send

```js
 ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

### Events

Note that you don't have the on('event') api
But instead
**onopen, onmessage, onclose**, ... methods to set

```js
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

Or by using **events** and **addEventListner**

```js
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

The total events are: **open, close, message, error**.

And it's nice to look out the doc, and also the tutorial here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Great! Is there any way to send headers using this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the websocket npm module with `npm install websocket`. Then write this at the beginning of the file, where you need the client.

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
```

NOTE: Browserify creates own scopes for all files when bundeling them. so WebSocketClient is not available in the scope, where it is used.